# Can I directly start a French Masters 2 with a UK 4 year integrated masters?

Tags: masters, university

I'm currently in my fourth and final year of my UK masters degree in Physics. The course is accredited as an MSci, equivalent to doing a 3 year Bsc followed by a 1 year Msc.

I'd like to apply to study nuclear engineering at Universite Paris-Saclay in France. The masters available there consists of a Masters 1 and a Masters 2, 2 successive years of study. I'm trying to find out if it's possible to start directly in the Masters 2, but it's difficult to figure out what exactly my MSci will be equivalent to. The course states it requires a Masters 1 or equivalent, but with no information on what it considers sufficient.

Under the bologna process, the UK masters is equivalent to the French (nominally), so in theory I'll already be above the required level.

Does anyone know of a student starting a French masters in the second year?

Comment: Given that you have a specific course and institution in mind, have you tried contacting them, explaining your situation, and asking them for more information? Getting the yay or nay from the administrators of the course you want to study would seem more useful to you than anecdotal evidence about students in similar (but not necessarily identical) situations.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, your integrated masters from the UK counts as a "Masters Européen"in France.

Source: I directly began a PhD immediately after finishing my MPhys in the UK, at Paris-Saclay, last year. If I was able to do that, I have doubts (although it's possible) that you would have trouble doing a M2 here.

As others have said, and as the other answer said, you should contact the university / admissions team as a first contact, to verify this. During the admission process you'll have to send your transcripts, and so in the end, they'll decide this for themselves. If it's anything like my admissions process, you will also have to send your MPhys dissertation, because it proves that you have done M2-equivalent work and a project with a significant time commitment and research result.

However, I'd be very surprised if you had any problem.

Answer (score 0):

As Ian_Fin commented, you should simply contact the person in charge. Search for the name (and possibly e-mail address) of the academic in charge, rather then administrative staff, faculty have the decision power. You usually also can make an application directly following any guidelines there.

There is no legal ground to prevent you to register, but you are not entitled either. I think your grade, motivation letter and possibly recommendations will be the most important parts. Try to add as much information as possible for grades, which are quite different in France (anything that makes clear what your grades mean to an outsider).